# Compare previous history route with current route in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

Is it possible to get previous back hit route and compare with current route if the user were in current page before in angularjs ng-route?
e.g
If user is on list feed and click on item then hit default/site back button to current page, the current page will known he/she was here before.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please provide more information about what you tried and what happend. Maybe it is good idea to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own routing history using $rootScope:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(ev, newUrl, oldUrl) {
    // Push previous Url into array.
    $rootScope.routes.push(oldUrl);
});
```

And then to compare with current route:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(ev, newUrl) {
    // Check if you've been here before.
    var visited = $rootScope.routes.indexOf(newUrl) !== -1;
});
```

Don't forget to inject *$rootScope* into your controllers:

```
App.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.routes = [];
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i've been searching for this since yesterday